# Qt and Android - handleActivityResult returned from a camera, uri null

Tags: android, c++, qt, camera, qandroidjniobject

I have done a code to capture image by using camera in my qt app. I am using QtAndroid to write a equivalent java code in Qt.

I have already opened the camera, captured the image, but uri returns null and suddenly app crash on above android pie version phones, and it properly work on android lolipop phones.

How can I get uri of captured image using QAndroid to write a Java equivalent code in Qt?

Here is the code I have done:

Code for opening camera :-

```
QAndroidJniObject ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/MediaStore", "ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE", "Ljava/lang/String;");
QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.object<jstring>());
QtAndroid::startActivity(intent.object<jobject>(), 101, this);
```

Code for getting image uri :-

```
void UiMan::handleActivityResult(int receiverRequestCode, int resultCode, const QAndroidJniObject 
&data)
{
  qDebug()<<"In handelActivityResult";
  jint RESULT_OK = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<jint>("android/app/Activity", "RESULT_OK");
  if (receiverRequestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
  {
    qDebug()<<"In If";
    QAndroidJniObject uri = data.callObjectMethod("getData", "()Landroid/net/Uri;");
    QAndroidJniObject dadosAndroid = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/MediaStore$MediaColumns", "DATA", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    QAndroidJniEnvironment env;
    jobjectArray projecao = (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(1, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), NULL);
    jobject projacaoDadosAndroid = env->NewStringUTF(dadosAndroid.toString().toStdString().c_str());
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(projecao, 0, projacaoDadosAndroid);
    QAndroidJniObject contentResolver = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod("getContentResolver", "()Landroid/content/ContentResolver;");
    QAndroidJniObject cursor = contentResolver.callObjectMethod("query", "(Landroid/net/Uri;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/database/Cursor;", uri.object<jobject>(), projecao, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    jint columnIndex = cursor.callMethod<jint>("getColumnIndex", "(Ljava/lang/String;)I", dadosAndroid.object<jstring>());
    cursor.callMethod<jboolean>("moveToFirst", "()Z");
    QAndroidJniObject resultado = cursor.callObjectMethod("getString", "(I)Ljava/lang/String;", columnIndex);

    QFile imageFile(resultado.toString());
    QDir dir;
    if(dir.exists("images")){
        qDebug()<<"Folder already exists";
    }else {
        dir.mkdir("images");
    }
    QStringList splitedImagePath = resultado.toString().split("/");
    QString imageName = splitedImagePath.value(splitedImagePath.length() - 1);
    QString dataimgFile = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation) + "/images/" + imageName;
    // /data/data/org.qtproject.feather/files/images/offLight_Button.png

    if (imageFile.exists())
    {
        QFile cdbfile(dataimgFile);
        if (!cdbfile.exists())
        {
            if(!imageFile.copy(dataimgFile))
                qDebug() << "Error :copy failed" ;

            QFile::setPermissions(dataimgFile, QFile::WriteOwner | QFile::ReadOwner);
        }

        else
        {
            qDebug() << "image exits allready no need to copy " ;
            QFile::setPermissions(dataimgFile, QFile::WriteOwner | QFile::ReadOwner);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "img Not exit in Assert " << dataimgFile;

    }

    QVariant imagePath = "file://" + dataimgFile;

    emit signalToQml(1148, imagePath, "", "","","","","","");
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Error";
}
```

}

So. please help me for solving this problem. and help me to write equivalent qt code is given below for getting bitmap of captured image,

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Comment: `opened the camera, captured the image and received the path, but uri returns null` Pretty strange sequence. Where would you capture a path and then receive yet an uri?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check.

Comment: `How can I get uri of captured image` You should supply an uri yourself where the camera app can write the image to. You use an extra in the camera intent to tell the camera app your uri.

Comment: `help me to write equivalent qt code is given below for getting bitmap of captured image,` That does not give you a bitmap of the image but only a bitmap of the thumbnail. Where you need it for?

Comment: My problem is  `QAndroidJniObject uri = data.callObjectMethod("getData", "()Landroid/net/Uri;");` This statement give null pointer exception in my pie mobile when capturing image, and it works totally fine on lolipop mobile. So, I don't no the solution of this problem. Please help me.

Comment: Tried your code. Don't get handleActivityResult called... Isn't a intent.callObjectMethod("setType",...) call missing before QtAndroid::startActivity?

Comment: My object (like here your UiMan object) was delete too early. Also getting an exception now.